# Getting User data from parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am stuck trying to wrap my head around the parse.com concept of parsing information. My problem is trying to open a webpage when the username is in my parse.com database. Example. The user enters "john" as username and "gan" as a password on the login screen. If the username is found i want to open a webpage lets say google.com. I think i got the concept sort of correct but i think my logic is wrong. Can someone help?

```java
public class Login extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(layout.activity_login);
  final   EditText username = (EditText) this.findViewById(id.userloginname);
    final EditText password = (EditText) this.findViewById(id.userpassword);


    TextView neighbourView = new TextView(this);

    Button button_test;
    button_test = (Button) this.findViewById(id.btnLogin);

    button_test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

          final  String usersname =  username.getText().toString();
          final  String passwoord = password.getText().toString();


            //ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Parking");
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(usersname, passwoord, new LogInCallback() {
                public void done(ParseUser User, com.parse.ParseException e) {

                    if (User != null) {

                                  // user name is in the database
                            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                            startActivity(browserIntent);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user name does not exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                }



            });
            // return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And my XML

```xml
     <!--  Username Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="@string/username"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/userloginname"
        android:inputType="text" />
    <!--  Password Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="@string/password"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:password="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/userpassword" />
    <!-- Login button -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/loginButton"/>
```

Comment: Did you add the permissions to the manifest? Are you calling Parse.initialize? Post your logcat

Comment: I added the dependancies and the parse library.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, i think is a permissions issue, or you forgot to copy the jars.

Some things to check:

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
}
```

Add this permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Then in the onCreate() you need to initialize parse

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, XXXX,XXXX);
```

The best way to do it is having a custom Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXX", "XXXXXX");
    }
}
```

Then in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
  android:name=".MyAplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
  <--!activities, etc-->
 </application>
```

Comment: i have all the dependancies and all the good stuff in the manifest. I guess the issue is which the onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

if its a new user you have to log in first, then you can use your code to login, if you are already logged in  new record will **not** added to the database, it'll identify the user and login.

```
        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if( e != null){
 ParseUser.logInInBackground(usersname, passwoord, new LogInCallback() {
                public void done(ParseUser User, com.parse.ParseException e) {

                    if (User != null) {

                                  // user name is in the database
                            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                            startActivity(browserIntent);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user name does not exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                }



            });


}
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I get this error *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must register this ParseObject subclass before instantiating it.*

Comment: This error comes because you need to add `ParseObject.registerSubclass(ClassName.class);` into the Application class. Since ParseUser is a provided by parse you don't need to add it to the Application class. May be there are other classes you used in your code which is not registered in the Application class.